# RoR 3 Hartl Tutorial: Moving Sign-Up page to the Home Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, registration

I am new to RoR3 am following along with the RoR3 Michael Hartl Tutorial. Out of interest, I want to move the sign-up html form to the home page rather than on a sign-up page. The code for the form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>

*** more fields ***

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Can't just be moved to the home page -- the code won't reference the user model properly to create a new user, and so the page doesn't load. How does one go about accomplishing the goal of moving this form to the home page of the site?

More info: the structure of the site follows the standard rails set-up (user model named user.rb in app/models/user.rb, controller in app/users_controller.rb, views are in app/views where there are folders for pages, layouts, and users folders. The current form is in app/views/users/new.html.erb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the home page, for example, uses the `PagesController` and the `home` action, and the route is `root :to => "pages#home"` or something similar, you need to instantiate the `@user` variable in the `home` action:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @user = User.new
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

When the form is rendered on the home page, it will have access to the `@user` variable.